# Python Pandas: Create Column That Acts As A Conditional Running Variable

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, conditional-statements

I'm trying to create a new dataframe column that acts as a running variable that resets to zero  or "passes" under certain conditions. Below is a simplified example of what I'm looking to accomplish. Let's say I'm trying to quit drinking coffee and I'm tracking the number of days in a row i've gone without drinking any. On days where I forgot to make note of whether I drank coffee, I put "forgot", and my tally does not get influenced.

Below is how i'm currently accomplishing this, though I suspect there's a much more efficient way of going about it.

Thanks in advance!

```
import pandas as pd

Day = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11]  
DrankCoffee = ['no','no','forgot','yes','no','no','no','no','no','yes','no']

df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(Day,DrankCoffee)), columns=['Day','DrankCoffee'])

df['Streak'] = 0  

s = 0

for (index,row) in df.iterrows():
   if row['DrankCoffee'] == 'no':
      s += 1
   if row['DrankCoffee'] == 'yes':
      s = 0
   else:
      pass

   df.loc[index,'Streak'] = s
```

[image]

Comment: Could you give more details of how the problem is structured? Because it seems you could use iloc and keep track of the last 0 in your streak column. Let us call it `zero_streak`. If the next entry is `yes` then just add +1 from the `zero_streak` index to current index. If `no` then set the new row for streak as 0 and update your `zero_streak` to the new index

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use `groupby.transform`

for each `streak`, what you're looking for is something like this:

```
def my_func(group):
    return (group == 'no').cumsum()
```

you can divide the different streak with simple comparison and `cumsum`

```
streak = (df['DrankCoffee'] == 'yes').cumsum()
```

> ```
> 0     0
> 1     0
> 2     0
> 3     1
> 4     1
> 5     1
> 6     1
> 7     1
> 8     1
> 9     2
> 10    2
> ```

then apply the transform

```
df['Streak'] = df.groupby(streak)['DrankCoffee'].transform(my_func)
```

Comment: Thanks!! All of the responses are great, but I think this one was the easiest for me to understand the step by step process.

Answer (score 3):

You need firstly map you DrankCoffee to [0,1](Base on my understanding `yes` and `forgot` should be 0 and `no` is 1), then we just do `groupby` `cumsum` to create the group key , when there is `yes` we start a new round for count those evens

```
df.DrankCoffee.replace({'no':1,'forgot':0,'yes':0}).groupby((df.DrankCoffee=='yes').cumsum()).cumsum()
Out[111]: 
0     1
1     2
2     2
3     0
4     1
5     2
6     3
7     4
8     5
9     0
10    1
Name: DrankCoffee, dtype: int64
```

Comment: mapping DrankCoffee to 0,1 can be easier with `== 'no'`

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
df['Streak'] = df.assign(streak=df['DrankCoffee'].eq('no'))\
                 .groupby(df['DrankCoffee'].eq('yes').cumsum())['streak'].cumsum().astype(int)
```

Output:

```
    Day DrankCoffee  Streak
0     1          no       1
1     2          no       2
2     3      forgot       2
3     4         yes       0
4     5          no       1
5     6          no       2
6     7          no       3
7     8          no       4
8     9          no       5
9    10         yes       0
10   11          no       1
```

1. First, create streak increment when 'no' then True.
2. Next, create streak when 'yes' start a new streak using cumsum().
3. Lastly, use cumsum to count streak increment in streaks with
   cumsum().